# Word Processor: Logic of continuous sections

Tags: vba, architecture, rendering, application-design, wordprocessingml

i'm writing something off-topic today because i like to understand how it works, the process of composing continuous sections in a word processing program, as you know it from Microsoft Word, Libre Office or Apple Pages.

I am currently writing my own Word Processor Control. This is supposed to be very extensive. I have two modules. One takes care of the data, the other takes care of the presentation of the data. So the second one is the renderer for the data class.

The structure of a data document with formatted texts can be roughly described as follows:

```
Document
  + Section (2 Columns)
    + Paragraph
      + Text
      + Tabstop
      + Text
      + Picture
    + Paragraph
      + Text
  + Section
    ...
```

So we have a data structure with one section, which in turn contains two paragraphs with different contents.
The render engine currently translates the whole thing as follows:

```
Document
  + Page
    + PageColumn (1. Column)
      + Blocks
        + Paragraph
          + Line
            + Text
            + Tabstop
            + Text
            + Picture
          ...
        + Paragraph
          + Line
            + Text
          ...
    + PageColumn (2. Column)
      + Blocks
        ...
```

The renderer calculates how many lines generated by the data structure fit into a paragraph. Then it looks again how many blocks (paragraph or table) fit in a column. If the height is exceeded, it continues in the next column and adds a new page if necessary.

This means that at the moment I can display "fixed" sections with my structure, i.e. those that start on Even/Odd/NextPage. For drawing the control, this simply means that for each page I output all columns from left to right, with the contents of the columns, the blocks then being drawn from top to bottom.

Within Word, Pages etc. it is possible, however, to display continuous sections on a page. Example:

```
Page
  Section (1 Column)
  Section (2 Columns)
  Section (1 Column)
```

How do you have to change the structure so that you can implement this? In a continuous section with more than one column, you somehow have to calculate in advance how many blocks and rows will fit into each column to get a balanced display result.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A section with two columns balances text across the columns because in reality it is one column which flows across the page.  The section expands to accommodate the total volume of text.  Typing in some text it seems that column 1 will take two lines of text before the cursor moves to column 2.  When the columns are balanced adding more text to column 2 reflows the text across the two columns, usually leaving two blank lines at the end of column 2 compared to column 1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So far I can understand it. Can you deduce a logic, an algorithm?